# How to expand the elements of an array in zsh?

Tags: arrays, zsh, variable-expansion

Say I have an array in zsh

```
a=(1 2 3)
```

I want to append `.txt` to each element

```
echo ${a}.txt # this doesn't work
```

So the output is

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

UPDATE:

I guess I can do this, but I think there's a more idiomatic way:

```
for i in $a; do
    echo $i.txt
done
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set `RC_EXPAND_PARAM` option:

```
$ setopt RC_EXPAND_PARAM
$ echo ${a}.txt
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

From zsh manual:

```
RC_EXPAND_PARAM (-P)
              Array  expansions of the form `foo${xx}bar', where the parameter xx is set to
              (a b c), are substituted  with  `fooabar  foobbar  foocbar'  instead  of  the
              default  `fooa  b  cbar'.   Note that an empty array will therefore cause all
              arguments to be removed.
```

You can also set this option just for for one array expansion using `^` flag:

```
$ echo ${^a}.txt
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
$ echo ${^^a}.txt
1 2 3.txt
```

Again citing zsh manual:

```
${^spec}
              Turn on the RC_EXPAND_PARAM option for the evaluation of spec; if the `^'  is
              doubled,  turn it off.  When this option is set, array expansions of the form
              foo${xx}bar, where the parameter xx is set to (a b c), are  substituted  with
              `fooabar foobbar foocbar' instead of the default `fooa b cbar'.  Note that an
              empty array will therefore cause all arguments to be removed.
```